# Cannot get SurveyMonkey Mobile SDK to work

Tags: android, surveymonkey

I am attempting to integrate SurveyMonkey into an app I am building. I signed up for a free SurveyMonkey Account and created a sample survey question. I also set up the Mobile SDK Collector as required. I followed the steps outlined on the GitHub page (https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/surveymonkey-android-sdk) for project setup. I copy/pasted the simple application and replaced the Survey Hash with my own. When I attempted to launch the survey, the survey refused to launch and received the following error:

```
com.surveymonkey.surveymonkeyandroidsdk.SMFeedbackActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.surveymonkey.surveymonkeyandroidsdk.SMFeedbackActivity$ConnectivityMonitor@19aceecc that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.surveymonkey.surveymonkeyandroidsdk.SMFeedbackActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.surveymonkey.surveymonkeyandroidsdk.SMFeedbackActivity$ConnectivityMonitor@19aceecc that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:960)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:761)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:2003)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1983)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1977)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
at com.surveymonkey.surveymonkeyandroidsdk.SMFeedbackActivity.onCreate(SMFeedbackActivity.java:67)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I looked through the API docs trying to figure this error out. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEK292, thanks for your post! I'm the SurveyMonkey engineer who works on the SDK. I've just released a new version of the SDK on our [Github](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/surveymonkey-android-sdk/releases/tag/1.0.2) that should fix your problem. If not, feel free to reach out via Github issues, or by commenting further on this post. Thanks again.